# Partition issue in Windows 7 Home Basic

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I have a HP Pavilion g series 64-bit laptop shipped with Windows 7 Home Basic. I want to use the Windows built-in tool for managing storage media and shrinking drive C: to make some unallocated space and make new partition, but am unable to do so.

Can anyone recommend me some partition software that can do this?

Comment: I don't understand, do you want to use the Windows 7 tool (Disk Management) or are you looking for alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Disk Management Utility is suitable for resizing and creating partitions. I would think it is part of Windows 7 Home Basic.

To find it, click on "Start" and right click on "Computer" then "Manage". You may be asked to confirm a UAC prompt.

Click on the "Disk Management" section.

If you right-click on the partition you want to shrink (here I've got two partitions, typicall you'll have one) and then choose "Shrink". You will only be able to decrease the amount of space you have free on the drive. Once you have done this, Right-click in the new space (black) and create a new partiion there.

[image]

If this does not work or you have difficulty, try a [GParted Live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/), or the GParted utitlity in a Ubuntu Live CD

Answer (score 0):

Use Easeus instead. It is 100X simpler, and better. Download the free version here:

http://www.easeus.com/download.htm

Answer (score 0):

[Partition Magic](http://us.norton.com/theme.jsp?themeid=partition_magic&depthpath=0&header=0) used to be quite good in my days.

However it is paid.

I guess now the Windows 7 native partition manager is good enough.